# Incorrect Ajax Response

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a user registration form and get the correct responses from the form validation on the server side (php) with ajax. Currently my success and error response handlers are working correctly but I also want to show error messages to the user if, for some reason, there is a database connect error or validation fails on the client side and an empty field in the form is passed in the post method. I have tried to implement these responses but I receive a response code: 200 on the error handler and not the specified status that I pass in the php code. Please view the comments in my code for what's not working.

**JS**

```
let firstname = $("#firstname").val();
  let surname = $("#surname").val();
  let email = $("#email").val();
  let username = $("#usernameSignup").val();
  var password = $("#passwordSignup").val();
  var passwordConfirm = $("#passwordConfirm").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "userRegistration.php",
    data: {
      firstname: firstname,
      surname: surname,
      email: email,
      usernameSignup: username,
      passwordSignup: password,
      passwordConfirm: passwordConfirm
    },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data.status); // This passes 200 to the console log if there is an empty field and if I remove the dbConn.php file. 
      console.log(data.message);
      console.log("Not Successful Test");
      if (data.status == "error") {
        console.log("Error, Didn't Execute Query"); // This error data.status response works
      } else if (data.status == "empty") {
        console.log("You have an empty field"); // Want to display this to console if a field is empty.
      } else if (data.status == "connectionError") {
        console.log("Didn't connect to database"); // Want to display this to console if unable to connect to database 
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.status);
      console.log("successfulTest");
      if (data.status == "success") {
        console.log("Registration was successful"); // This success data.status works 
      }
    }
  });
```

**userRegistration.php**

```
<?php
// try catch statement to connect to database through getConnection() function in dbConn.php file
try {
    require_once("dbConn.php");
    $dbConn = getConnection();

    // Form validation for POST method to check fields are not empty and sets variables for sql query later. 
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $firstname = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'firstname') ? $_POST['firstname'] : null;
        $firstname = trim($firstname);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['surname']) && !empty($_POST['surname'])) {
        $surname = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'surname') ? $_POST['surname'] : null;
        $surname = trim($surname);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'email') ? $_POST['email'] : null;
        $email = trim($email);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['usernameSignup']) && !empty($_POST['usernameSignup'])) {
        $usernameSignup = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'usernameSignup') ? $_POST['usernameSignup'] : null;
        $usernameSignup = trim($usernameSignup);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passwordSignup']) && !empty($_POST['passwordSignup'])) {
        $passwordSignup = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'passwordSignup') ? $_POST['passwordSignup'] : null;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passwordConfirm']) && !empty($_POST['passwordConfirm'])) {
        $passwordConfirm = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'passwordConfirm') ? $_POST['passwordConfirm'] : null;
    }

    // Checks to see if both passwords entered match, to set the passwordHash variable.
    if ($passwordSignup == $passwordConfirm) {
        $passwordHash = password_hash($passwordSignup, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

    // If all the previous steps are valid and variables are set, try to run the SQL query to make new account.
    if ($firstname && $surname && $email && $usernameSignup && $passwordHash) {
        try {
            $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', 0, '$usernameSignup', '$passwordHash')";
            $execute = $dbConn->exec($sqlQuery);
            $response_array["status"] = "success";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $response_array["status"] = "error";
        }
    } else {
        $response_array["status"] = "empty"; // Should pass "empty" if any of the fields are empty
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response_array["status"] = "connectionError"; // Should pass "connectionError" if unable to connect to dbConn.php file
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response_array);
exit;
```

Comment: why you put `exit;` in the end?

Comment: To terminate the current script after sending response

Comment: see my solution below

Comment: I think php has terminate as soon as `echo` appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problems in your JS code. My test result:

[image]

The problem is: You put `success` option inside `error` option

Fix:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/admin/site/test",
        data: {
             Your data
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.status); // This passes 200 to the console log if there is an empty field and if I remove the dbConn.php file.
            console.log(data.message);
            console.log("Not Successful Test");
            if (data.status == "error") {
                console.log("Error, Didn't Execute Query"); // This error data.status response works
            } else if (data.status == "empty") {
                console.log("You have an empty field"); // Want to display this to console if a field is empty.
            } else if (data.status == "connectionError") {
                console.log("Didn't connect to database"); // Want to display this to console if unable to connect to database
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.status);
            console.log("successfulTest");
            if (data.status == "success") {
                console.log("Registration was successful"); // This success data.status works
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out, but I actually did not put the success option inside of the error option. I must have missed a closing bracket when copying and pasting to SO.

Comment: I still receive the response code: 200 on the error option handler

Comment: I don't have computer to make more test now, so I've check and maintained your JS, so It's worked for me, May be your JS after fixed is true. You can check your PHP code by the way: "put `var_dump($yourvariable);exit;` at where you want to stop and see variables status state (include $e exception)" and see it at : `inspect=>networktab => your request => response`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what this means